# Ubuntu 19.04 - Unable to connect to Home Wifi

Tags: networking, network-manager, lenovo, 19.04, ideapad

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 19.04 from LTS 18.04, and unable to connect to home wifi.

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

I am using intel Wireless 7260:

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ sudo lshw -class network

[sudo] password for swarna: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 08
       serial: 08:9e:01:ec:56:91
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0504000-b0504fff memory:b0500000-b0503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:6f:5b:a8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-21-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.225.78 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:46 memory:b0400000-b0401fff
```

I felt that the problem is due to crda, due to the error `Process '/sbin/crda' failed with exit code 255.` in the log, and added IND to the REGDOMAIN:

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ cat /etc/default/crda
# Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set
# the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate
# on this system.
#
# Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within
# their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2
# country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local
# legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' for a table of timezone
# descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

REGDOMAIN=IND
```

and rebooted the system. But still got:

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ crda
COUNTRY environment variable not set.
```

Also I changed setregdomain to also have IND as REGDOMAIN

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:/lib/crda$ cat setregdomain
#!/bin/sh

set -e

REGDOMAIN=IND
CRDA_CONF=/etc/default/crda

[ -r "$CRDA_CONF" ] && . "$CRDA_CONF"
[ -z "$REGDOMAIN" ] && exit 0

exec /sbin/iw reg set "$REGDOMAIN"
```

and did a reboot.

Still the same -

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ crda
COUNTRY environment variable not set.
```

I have also tried the following(after going through various suggestions available on internet), but nothing worked:

```
sudo service network-manager restart; reboot
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1; reboot
sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi; reboot
```

I am able to connect to other wi-fis with nothing changed at all. I have dual boot on my system, and windows connects fine with my home wifi.

Also, I am not sure if the crda problem is just a red herring and there is something else that needs to be fixed.

I am unable to proceed after this. Can someone please advise as to what I might be doing wrong and help me fix the problem? Kindly let me know if any other info is required to be attached.

**Post the answer, here are the logs:**

[output_IN](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16WcVtdG2SWbSKqHmz0kdKPmar0Bz2Q-6ePnREfUujVw/edit?usp=sharing)

I have modified /etc/default/crda to hold `REGDOMAIN=IN` as suggested:

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:/var/log$ cat /etc/default/crda
# Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set
# the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate
# on this system.
#
# Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within
# their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2
# country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local
# legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' for a table of timezone
# descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

REGDOMAIN=IN
```

I have also removed my changes from /lib/crda/setregdomain:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

REGDOMAIN=
CRDA_CONF=/etc/default/crda

[ -r "$CRDA_CONF" ] && . "$CRDA_CONF"
[ -z "$REGDOMAIN" ] && exit 0

exec /sbin/iw reg set "$REGDOMAIN"
```

Now I get

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ iw reg get
global
country IN: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5350 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
```

but:

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ crda
COUNTRY environment variable not set.
```

Also I tried connecting to another wifi, I did not see the crda error in that case, and the connection was successful.

```
swarna@swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15:~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  SSID                 MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       Lakme                Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2 
        JioFi4_0413B0        Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   52      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        IvanDominic          Infra  3     135 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Abhi2316@kbroadband  Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  WPA2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suspect that crda is not the entire problem, I suggest that we address it first and check the log for any improvement.

The file you reference above says, in part:

> Set REGDOMAIN to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code

If you search for ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2, one of the very first hits is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 We see that country codes ar all two letters, not three letters. I suspect that you want IN.

Of course, substitute your country code if not India. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IN
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Reboot.

Is there any improvement? Please post the log messages as above if not.

**EDIT**: First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Comment: yes, IN is correct, but it did not resolve the issue - I have added new logs  in the question. Please check and let me know. I am going through it too, though I am not sure if I would be able to get to the root cause. Please serach for "Post the answer, here are the logs" in this post for ease.

Comment: Also, I was able to connect to the home wifi miraculously, just now. I am not sure yet if the solution really worked. Will check the logs once again.

Comment: These are the logs from when it connected - https://docs.google.com/document/d/15XhkV7n4x444qLsu7IZNCRTQATLAGCJ41CQGhyqTopY/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Musing aloud - when it did not connect:
This happened:
Aug  7 19:48:30 swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15 wpa_supplicant[999]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
        Aug  7 19:48:33 swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15 kernel: [  376.950327] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 78:32:1b:62:88:86 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
        Aug  7 19:48:33 swarna-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-15 wpa_supplicant[999]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=78:32:1b:62:88:86 reason=15

And when it connected, no handshake time out. I am a noob on networks, so not sure how much further to dig in.

Comment: May we see a paste (Google docs?) of: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Will do a couple more reboots, today and tomorrow. This is naive, but I am not able to figure out the root cause from the logs.

Comment: Neither can I quite yet and I know a thing or two about networking. Not naive at all.

Comment: I have added the nmcli output on the question now. Please check.

Comment: I have added:
Mode 802.11b/g/n
Channel 1
BandWidth 20M
Security Options WPA2-PSK(AES)

for my D-Link router and rebooted it. It seems to be working for now. Will check this for a few days(2 or 3). Will accept and upvote your answer when that works, thanks. Also, can you please let me know how you came upon the answer/settings? I would like to know a bit more, a networking 101(any links would be helpful), if you please.

Comment: Please check here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5bQ59pN8ky/